# Re-launching Safari using Record and Run Settings in HP UFT

Tags: macos, vbscript, safari, qtp, hp-uft

I plan on running test scripts from UFT in a Safari browser in a Mac environment. I understand UFT 12.02 supports such functionality through its “Record and Run Settings” where users could select “Apple Safari (on remote Mac computer)” to launch Safari on a remote Mac to run test cases on.

However, is there a way to re-launch the Safari browser remotely after closing it, without having to go through the Record and Run Settings panel? That's one of my test cases.

Just to clarify, I currently use the **Systemutil.Run** function on Windows to help re-launch browsers automatically after closing them. Based on my understanding and trials, that function is designed to only work on Windows.

Is there a similar function we could use on Mac to re-launch Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SystemUtil.Run` is for running stuff on the local machine, you want to be using  [`RemoteConnection`](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/Latest/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/Remote_Connection_Setup.htm?Highlight=RemoteConnection).

According to the documentation `RemoteConnection.Run "safari"` can be used to launch Safari.

<strike>I'm not sure what format the *Appliation* parameter should be (full path or just `"safari"`) since I don't have  a Mac at hand. Please update if it works so future seekers will have a full answer.</strike> (thanks to [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6025943/stephen) for answering this in the comment).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. For those who are wondering, putting `"safari"` in the parameter is sufficient enough; no need to provide the full path.